# what is the difference between two similar sentences

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, usage

Do these two sentences have the exactly same meaning and usage: 
"I understand some people will feel that we are locating rioters or protesters inside hospital seems..."
"I understand some people will feel that our locating rioters or protesters at hospitals seems..."

Answer (score 1):

The second one is grammatical, but quite literary (the use of "our" with an "-ing" word is something that many people would not use in speech.)

The first is not grammatical because there is no noun phrase to act as the subject of "seems". To make it grammatical you would need something like "I understand some people will feel that **the fact that** we are locating rioters or protesters inside hospital seems..." Having said that, this makes a long and complicated sentence even longer and more complicated, and it might be better recast.

Comment: thanks,so,actually which one is better using in an announcement and the most important is that whether those have the same meaning in any viewing angle.

Comment: @HaHaSun It's impossible to give accurate advice because you haven't provided complete sentences or a context. However, I suspect it should be broken into two sentences: *We are locating rioters and protesters inside the hospital. Some people might find this . . . but . . .*